# Filtros con resultado invertido

Tags: powerbi

Tengo casi un mes intentando resolver un problema en mi informe y no he encontrado la solución... Espero ustedes me puedan ayudar.

En mi informe tengo una tabla de ventas con la siguiente información (pondré sólo lo relevante): = "CLI: Nombre", "CLI: Categoría", "ART: Nombre", "ART: Cantidad"

Tengo una segmentación de datos para filtrar por CLI: Categoría y una visualización en forma de tabla que me muestra todas las columnas que mencioné de mi tabla.

La funcionalidad hasta el momento es correcta, puedo filtrar por categoría y luego ordenar la visualización en base a la cantidad del artículo. El problema es que mi intención, es ver de la categoría filtrada, los clientes que NO tienen ventas para así saber de mi artículo TOP (por ejemplo), qué clientes de esa categoría no compran y ofrecerlo.

[image: Mi visualización de clientes]

[image: Mi visualización de artículos]

Al usar el filtro me muestra la lista de clientes que realizaron compras, pero quiero ver los que tienen cero compras...